# Cron Job not running via PHP Script

Tags: php, linux, cron

Firstly, I have built PHP scripts that run as a cron job when I set it up in linux and it works fine.

What I am doing in the script is writing to a file which isn't being done but works fine via CURL in terminal.

example (the first thing that happens in the script) :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$fp2 = fopen('FeedLog.csv', 'w');

fputcsv($fp2,array("Started Cron",date("F j, Y, g:i a"),0));
```

I feel like there is some sort of permission issue? I have set both the script and the file its writing to, to 777.

There are no errors or anything in logs nor output.

Comment: You'd want to specify an absolute path to that Feedlog.csv file. Under cron, a script's working directory will be the home directory of the user the script's running under, which is mostl likely NOT where the script file is located. If it was a permission error, you can check it by adding some error handling: `if (!$fp2) { die ("Unable to open file"); }`

Comment: Try using an absolute path to the file instead of relative.

Comment: I have a different thought, make sure the php binary /usr/bin/php is accessible via the crontab user

Comment: Hmm, this does make sense and I will try it in a moment, however, shouldn't this create an error if it could't open the file?   I mean the script continues execution until its complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either try a absolute path to the file in fopen, or use chdir to change to the correct directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
chdir('/home/user/');
$fp2 = fopen('FeedLog.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp2,array("Started Cron",date("F j, Y, g:i a"),0));
```